# How to find the equation of motion of a body falling towards a star?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, geodesics

I need help understanding the procedure used to find the (relativistic)  equation of motion of a body falling towards a star, I know bodies naturally follow a geodesic trajectory, can I use this fact?
 Can you provide an example?

Comment: Can we neglect the star rotation about its own axis? (I mean can I assume a Schwartzchild metric?)

Comment: This is prohibitively hard in full general relativity if you allow a general shape for the star, and if the infalling body has size and extent.

Comment: Don't just ask people to do your homework for you. Show your work so far and ask a *specific* question about where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

In General Relativity, a test mass (small mass which itself doesn't affect the space-time curvature significantly) is assumed, in free-fall, to follow the geodesics of the space-time it is in. Given a space-time metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ one can obtain a (metric) geodesic equation: $\nabla_{\vec{U}}\vec{U}=0$, where $\vec{U}$ is the tangent vector to the geodesic curve, and $\nabla$ is the derivative associated with the metric connection (rule for parallel transport).  The coordinate form of the geodesic equation is:
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}U^\alpha +\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}U^\beta U^\gamma = 0$$ where $\lambda$ is the (affine) parameter along the geodesic and $\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}$ are the Christoffel symbols associated with the metric. That's the rule for finding the geodesics of the space-time, and once the geodesics of the space-time are found, we know that those are the paths through spacetime that a freely falling test particle follows. Picking which specific path a particle follows, of course, requires some knowledge of some initial conditions of that particle (pick a space-time point that that particle's world line passes through, and give the 4-velocity of the particle at that point). For a more in-depth look at geodesics [see the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Examples). For a look at how to get the Christoffel symbols given a metric see [its Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols).

So, that's the first half of the problem: finding the geodesics given the spacetime metric. The other half of the problem is "given some distribution of matter, find the spacetime". That problem is notoriously difficult. Formally, the way to approach that problem is via the Einstein Field Equations: 
$G_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}$.
Here, $G_{\mu\nu}$ is the [Einstein tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor), and $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the [stress energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).
But these field equations are highly non-linear and extremely difficult to find exact solutions for. Luckily, if we are in a vacuum (e.g. outside of the star in your example), we can at least set $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ and solve the vacuum Einstein equations. Only a select few exact solutions to the Einstein Field Equations are known, the most famous of which is the Schwarzschild solution which gives the metric for a spherically symmetric (vacuum) spacetime. We often use the Schwarzschild solution as an approximation to the exterior solution of a star because it's one of the simplest metrics to work with. Another metric that might approximate the exterior spacetime of a star would be the Kerr metric which a vacuum solution that accounts for an angular momentum (i.e. if the star is spinning). For more on the Scwharzschild metric, see [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric); for more on the Kerr metric, see [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric).

So the general procedure to finding the EOM for test particles in the gravitational field of a star would be, 1. decide which spacetime to use to approximate the gravitational field of the star (Schwarzschild? Kerr? Something more exotic? Or perhaps using some sort of post-Newtonian approximations to get approximate spacetimes?) and then 2. find the geodesics of those spacetimes using the geodesic equation and lastly 3. input some initial conditions to determine which exact path that particle is moving on.

Like others have said in comments. This procedure is QUITE difficult most of the time. And there are a myriad of tricks that one could use to perhaps make these calculations more tractable (one trick worth mentioning is finding symmetries of the space-time and employing the use of conserved quantities, see the idea behind [Killing vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) for more information) Also, if your test particle is not a "test" particle and is massive enough that it itself gives a significant contribution to the spacetime curvature, then you run into a two-body problem in GR which, as far as I know, has not been exactly solved. It is beyond the scope of a Stack Exchange post to provide a full solution to the problem you are asking. And depending on the specifics of the question (how are we modeling the star? how big is the test particle? etc.), a full solution might not be known. But hopefully, this post provides you with a good starting point in exploring the problem.